# Не запускается Windows 7 в загрузчике Grub2

Tags: linux, windows-7, grub, dual-boot

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стояла Windows 7 на разделе sda2. Решил поставить Ubuntu 16.04. Поставил её на расширенный раздел sda4 (sda5, sda6, sda7). При старте появился загрузчик grub2, через который не запускается Windows 7.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Т.е. после выбора в меню Windows 7 и нажатия Enter grub пытается загрузить винду, после чего выкидывается обратно в меню.

Меня смущает то, что в меню grub2 указано, что винда находится на разделе sda1, хотя по факту она стоит на sda2.
Подскажите пожалуйста как можно исправить загрузчик grub2, чтобы запускалась Windows7.

Файлик /boot/grub/grub.cfg

Comment: при выделении пункта меню нажмите кнопку e - можно будет редактировать запись. Остальные кнопки там само подскажет. Если все отработает, тогда нужно  будет конфиг груба править

Comment: Всё отработало, но я не могу скопировать от туда текст.  Где этот файл находится? Его можно просто открыть через gedit?
Открыл файл sudo gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg, это он?

Comment: У меня была подобная проблема с Альт Линукс после того, как я при установке загрузчик граба поставил в жесткий диск, а не на тот раздел, куда сам Линукс ставил. Так и не исправил загрузку виндовс оттуда, но выход нашел - с помощью диска Виндовс Vista восстановил загрузку виндовс: теперь при загрузке стандартный виновый загрузчик (черный) дает выбор винды или линукса (а в линуксе в граб линукс выбираю).

Comment: Вообщем не знаю как сюда выложить, выложил текст файлика /boot/grub/grub.cfg сюда http://jsbin.com/naseharuwu/edit?css,output

Comment: попробуйте убрать boot-флаг с sda1 и поставить этот флаг на sda2. после чего обновите конфигурацию grub: `$ sudo update-grub` и смотрите, не поменялось ли что-то в меню. перезагружаться для этого даже не надо: будет сгенерирован новый файл `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, сравните его с (предварительно) сохранённой копией.

Comment: если установка boot-флага не поможет, можно [добавить кастомную секцию](https://askubuntu.com/a/618497/416190). только в вашем случае, как я понимаю, будет `hd0,msdos2`, а не `hd0,msdos1`

Comment: Я и раньше пробовал убирать флаг с sda 1 и ставить на sda2, но не помогало. Просто нужно еще было обновить update-grub. Так что большое спасибо, вопрос снят.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В программе gparted нужно снять флаг с sda1 и поставить на sda2, после чего выполнить команду update-grub.